# AG grid get selected rows at group index

Tags: angular, ag-grid

**Note:** Grid data is grouped.

I'm trying to get selected rows at specific group index.

I tried `getDisplayedRowAtIndex(index).allLeafChildren` and loop through each node for selected true, this will give what I need, but only on first render.

Any idea! How to achieve the same?
Thanks

Comment: have you checked getBestCostNodeSelection() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have yo use [group-key](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#grouping-api) for target-reference and then go through `allLeafChildren` loop-check

```
gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.key == 'needed key here') {
        node.allLeafChildren.forEach(gNode=>{
            if(gNode.selected){
                //your logic here
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that trick,  but I don't want to go through 1000s of records.

Comment: might be you can get it via ID if you will define it for groups.